# Vue v-model doesn't trigger with third party dropdowns

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, vue.js, selectize.js

I have a select element defined as

```
<select v-model="mySelectValue">
    <option v-for=...>...</option>
</select>
```

If used as is, `mySelectValue` is updated correctly when the user changes the select input.

Now I want to style the input. I tried [Selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/):

```
$('select').selectize();
```

The select input is now using the new look and functionality but changing the value doesn't update `mySelectValue`. I thought that the original select input would get updated with Selectize.js so I tried [Dropdown.js](https://github.com/FezVrasta/dropdown.js). Same thing.

Using jQuery I hooked a on change listener to the original select input:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function() { 
    console.log($(this).val()); 
});
```

Using either of those two libraries I see the change event triggered and the original select input updated.

Why isn't Vue updating `mySelectValue`?

Comment: Did you hooked the change listener before or after the `selectize` call? I suspect, these libraries remove the element from dom and reinsert it somewhere else stripping all attached handlers and such.

Comment: @MathewJibin I checked the DOM: The original element is still intact. Both libraries set `display: none` and insert their own custom structure after the original select element. Using Chrome dev tools, I made the original element visible again and tried altering it's value. It still triggers `v-model` change in Vue. This also gave visual confirmation that the original and the custom dropdown are linked as updating either one changed the other.

Comment: good to know, try changing the value from console using jquery `val` method, does it still triggers it? someone somewhere inside the library might be suppressing the event bubble maybe to avoid circular update or something?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a value attribute to `<option>`

```
<select v-model="mySelectValue">
   <option value='1'>one</option>
   <option value='2'>two</option>
   <option value='3'>three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I do have value attributes but I removed them from my snippets in the question.